# I want to release Korean domain web service with nginx

Tags: nginx, dns

I want to release my web service.

Its domain is Korean.

So I set server_name both unicode and punycode but It doesn't work.

```
server {
    server_name 벌레.com xn--om2bp6f.com;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8002;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

But when I access to domain, It always displays 'welcome to nginx'. 
Help!
If I change domain to another english domain, it works well.

Comment: I notice that the website is redirected to `www.벌레.com`. Maybe you need to add `www.` variants to your `server_name` or find out why you are being redirected to `www`.

Comment: Oh my god thank you Mr. Smith